# The Qt package does not want to start. No Qt platform plugin could be initialized

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt

`your text`This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be intialized. Reinstalling the application may application may fix this problem. I tried reinstalling - didn't help. Below is the code on which I experienced this error. I hope they can help me, if possible, of course xD)

> ```
> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
> ```

```
import sys


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.Qwidget()
window.setWindowtittle("Программа на PyQt")
window.resize(300, 150)
label = QtWidgets.Qlabel("<center>Привет, я надпись!</center>")
btnQuit = QtWidgets.QpushButton("Закрыть окно")
btnQuit.clicked.connect(app.quit)
box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(label)
box.addWidget(btnQuit)
window.setLayout(box)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

First, I used cmd, where I entered the command "pip installed PyQt5". As a result, it was written that the package was installed, but the error remained in PyCharm. After, I used the Python Package, the problem remained. On the Internet, I came across dozens of ways, I used three, none of them helped. As a result, I despaired and wrote here, with the hope of a solution.  I hope they can help me, if possible, of course xD)

Comment: See [ask] and [mre]. Provide detailed debugging information such as stack traces, logs, OS version, Python distribution(official, anaconda, etc.), Python version, etc.